# DotNenuke Razor Host RenderPage pass in dynamic variablwe

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I'm working with DNN 8.4.2 - 
My partial looks like this this:

```
@{
if(ViewBag.loadItem != null && ViewBag.loadItem)
{
//load my stuff
}
}
```

While my rendering looks like this:

```
@RenderPage("Shared/MyScript.cshtml",new{ loadItem = true })
```

But, when the page loads, i'm getting the following exception:
The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context.

Is there anyway I can pass in a dynamic variable to a partial rendering in DNN's razor host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer!
There is no `ViewBag`in DNN's Razor Host module since it only works with a Model. You can use `PageData` instead.

```
var loadItem = PageData["loadItem"];
    if (loadItem != null && loadItem)
    {
        //do stuff here
    }
```